# Easel Js works with a canvas in the html document but it doesn't work when I put the canvas in an HTML widget in my GWT HTML widget it doesn't work

Tags: html, gwt, canvas, easeljs, jsni

I went in the host html page and put

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200">
         alternate content
    </canvas>
```

Then I went in a JSNI method and put

```
$wnd.$('#canvas').ready(function() {
    console.log('ds');
    $wnd.stage = new $wnd.createjs.Stage("canvas");
    $wnd.stage.addChild(new $wnd.createjs.Shape()).set({x:100,y:100}).graphics.f("red").dc(0,0,50);
    $wnd.stage.update();
});
```

It worked. But then I cut and paste the canvas element from the html host page to an HTML widget in my GWT code. It didn't work. It didn't give me an error. It simply didn't do anything.

I tried to pass in the element but document.getElementById() didn't work. Why didn't it work? Is the stuff in UiBinder some how not part of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `getElementById()`. Here is what should work. In UI Binder:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
     <canvas ui:field="canvas" width="200" height="200">
         alternate content
     </canvas>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In you Java view class:

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.$;

@UiField
Element canvas;
```

Pass `canvas` into your JSNI function. and it should work passing the canvas object to EaselJs.

Comment: I kind of did that and it worked. The only difference is that I used GWT's Canvas wrapper around canvas rather than the actual html element. like you did.

Comment: Well you can do both.